# Why the error "generic type requires 1 type argument" when initiating variable?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand the error below. What argument am I expected to pass in and how?

**Code**

```
interface ActiveRequest<TServerResponse extends IBaseServerResponse> {
    transactionId: string;
    resolve: (value: TServerResponse) => void;
    reject: (reason: Error) => void;
    timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
}

...


protected activeRequests: Array<ActiveRequest> = [];
```

**Error**

```
[ts] Generic type 'ActiveRequest<TServerResponse>' requires 1 type argument(s).
interface ActiveRequest<TServerResponse extends IBaseServerResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined `TServerResponse` as a generic type for `ActiveRequest` so anytime you use `ActiveRequest` you need to define a specific type for it, which will be used as a reference for `TServerResponse`.

That means, instead of `Array<ActiveRequest>`, you must use `Array<ActiveRequest<SomeTypeHere>>` and `SomeTypeHere` must be extended from `IBaseServerResponse` type, likes `TServerResponse` does

Answer (score 0):

with the syntax `interface ActiveRequest<TServerResponse extends IBaseServerResponse> {` you are defining an interface with a Generic (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). That means whenever you are using said interface you have to provide the type also in `<`and `>`

In your case for example `protected activeRequests: Array<ActiveRequest<TServerResponse>> = [];`

Answer (score 0):

`<TServerResponse extends IBaseServerResponse>` means you have to pass one type but this type must extends IBaseServerResponse. If you want to have default type you can use `<TServerResponse = IBaseServerResponse>`